# CyclePagerIndicator чем заменить?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

CyclePagerIndicator в проект добавить нужно. На гитхабе и вообще нашел лишь зависимость к мавен. Чем можно ее заменить?

Comment: а чем плохая мавен зависимость? Ну и в целом вопрос "чем заменить" - боюсь ответ будет "чем угодно"

Comment: @pavel ну мавен же в градле нельзя прописать. Чем угодно? хотите сказать самоделку? или вы знаете библиотеку?

Comment: @user8978194 А скиньте maven "зависимость"

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете Gradle, то добавить в зависимости это:

```
compile 'com.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1'
```

Если что-то другое, то посмотрите [здесь](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.viewpagerindicator%7Clibrary%7C2.4.1%7Capklib)

Comment: Это первый проект на который гуглится "CyclePagerIndicator" и там есть класс "CyclePagerIndicator"